# Angular MatDatePicker

Tags: html, angular

I use matte DatePicker for input and output date selection. [MatDatepicker] = It works when I type "Selector". When you give someone a different name, only [matDatepicker] = "selector" works and the other gives an error. How can I fix?

```
<mat-form-field>
    <label>Entry Date?</label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <label>Pay Date?</label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but it sounds like you are wanting to have two date pickers but are struggling since you need to provide a different name for `[matDatePicker]`. Your `picker` value needs to match your binding on the `<mat-datepicker>`

Example:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <label>Entry Date?</label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #startDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <label>Pay Date?</label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="endDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="endDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #endDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here's a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/angular/lyeebaxdmyd

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I link the change Start Date and Change EndDate methods given here to filter these dates? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60239140/type-script-filtering-between-2-dates